# How to add ruby on rails website in cpanel (godaddy VPS hosting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cpanel, vps

I created a VPS server in godaddy , and created a website here. under that i saw the cpanel link. on click of that it takes me to cpanel home page. but  i am unable to add my folder in cpanel. my application developed on Ruby on rails. but in cpanel i couldn't see an option called rubyonrails under software. why it is like that. 
THIS IS MY CPANEL SCREENSHOT. how can i add ror application here
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you rent vps hosting, likely you have ssh account to login to your VPS server

so first get ssh access first:

1. Click Web Hosting.
2. Next to the cPanel account you want to use, click Manage.
3. Click cPanel Admin.
4. In the Security section, click SSH Access.
5. Click Enable.

then you can login into it, and follow following tutorial to setup your rails app

godaddy.com/help/installing-ruby-on-rails-ror-on-linux-12160

Comment: where i can see  Web Hosting.?u mean in  godaddy?

Comment: you can try to read following blog
maybe it helps
https://www.pixelleak.com/tech/how-to/ssh-godaddy-cpanel-hosting/
https://in.godaddy.com/help/enable-ssh-16102

Comment: will godaddy support ruby on rails hosting?

Comment: you said that you've rent a VPS, so that means you could install anything in your server, including ruby on rails. Ruby on Rails is not one click install app like wordpress, it's a framework to create web application

Comment: That article doesn't tell you how to get the site into CPanel, though. Just how to run a test app at the IP using rails server

Comment: Yes correct. Setting up ruby on rails on production server is long journey for beginner, and having ssh access in your vps is most important part